# dependency with file separator not resolving in gradle 6.0 version

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am upgrading my spring boot project to gradle 6.0. After upgrading to gradle 6.0 below dependency is not resolving. Is there anything changed with gradle 6.0 dealing with file separator. Below are the details.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip
distributionUrl=http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-6.0-bin.zip
```

dependencies.gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

      
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/prerelease' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/public' }
}


dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    implementation('com/zoom/ans:complete-order:dmz.100')
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

gradle.properties

```
group=com.zoom.order
projectVersion=1

# Dependencies
springBootVersion=2.1.3.RELEASE
springBootGradlePluginVersion=2.1.3.RELEASE
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/internal-artifacts" }
        maven { url "http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/public" }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootGradlePluginVersion}"
        
    }
}

// Community Plugins
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'



version = projectVersion + '.' + version;

// Project plugins
apply from: "${projectDir}/gradle/dependencies.gradle"

// Spring Boot Properties
bootRun {
    systemProperties = [ 'spring.config.location' : "file:src/main/config/runtime/local/", 'ExstreamPass_ExitCodeThreshold':8,
        'logging.config' : "$projectDir/src/main/config/runtime/local/log4j2.json",
        'LOG_PATH' : 'C:/logs' ]
   jvmArgs = [ "-Dlogging.config=$projectDir/src/main/config/runtime/local/log4j2.json" ]
}

task qualify(dependsOn: [check, test]) {
    doLast{ println project.name + ' : qualified' }
}
```

below is the grale build exception

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com/zoom/ans:complete-order:dmz.100.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:361)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:354)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:340)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1293)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2300(DefaultConfiguration.java:140)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitStructure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.visitStructure(DefaultConfiguration.java:504)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitStructure(CompositeFileCollection.java:181)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.lambda$visitInputFileProperties$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:306)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$fingerprintInputFiles$3(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitInputFileProperties(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:304)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.fingerprintInputFiles(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:188)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionStateOp$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateOp(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com/zoom/ans:complete-order:dmz.100.
Required by:
project :
```

Below are dependency library project configuration details. Below one is publishing the jar (complete-order:dmz.100) to repository.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {  
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/maven' }
        maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
        classpath 'com.zoom.ebe:internal-artifacts:+'
        classpath 'com.zoom.ebe:jar-stamper:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea' 
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'build-dashboard'
apply plugin: 'project-report'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'com.zoom.ebe.jar-stamper'
apply plugin: 'com.zoom.ebe.internal-artifacts'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

def currentJvm = org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
println currentJvm

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8



project.ext {
    app_name='ANS'
    build_date=new Date().format("yyyyMMddHHmm")
    release_number='R1.0'
    groupId="com.zoom.ans"
    rc_build="${System.env.BUILD_NUMBER}" //look for BUILD_NUMBER in env (set by Jenkins)
    buildID = "ANS_CompleteOrder_Full"
    
    fortify_build_id='ANS_CompleteOrder_Full'
    sonar_projectkey='ANS_CompleteOrder'
    sonar_projectname='ANS Complete Order'
}


group 'com.zoom.ans'



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/internal-artifacts' } // this repository is designed for internal-artifacts publishing
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/zoom-local' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/prerelease' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/external' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/maven' }
    ivy {
        url 'http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/maven'
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision](-[classifier]).xml"
        }
    }
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = false
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
    }
}


findbugsMain { ignoreFailures = false }
findbugsTest { ignoreFailures = true }
pmdMain { ignoreFailures = false }
pmdTest { ignoreFailures = true }

checkstyleMain {
    source = 'src/main/java'
}

checkstyle{
    ignoreFailures = true
    showViolations = false
}

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = !xml.enabled
    }
}

// Additional dependency configurations.
configurations {
    fortify { extendsFrom compile }
}

clean {
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/")
    delete file("dist/")
}

dependencies {
    checkstyle "com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:8.14"
    
    fortify "com.fortify:sourceanalyzer:3.90"
    
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+"
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'
    compile 'org.beanio:beanio:2.0.7'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4'
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.zoom.etc.storage:payx-object-storage:2.0.x.master.+'
    compile 'com.zoom.traceability:zoom-traceability-mark-library:2.1.4.master.+'
    compile 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1'
    
    //Jackson -JSON parser for java
    //compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.1'
    

    testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.+'
    testCompile "org.easyb:easyb:0.9.6"
    testCompile "org.easyb:easyb-junit:0.5.3"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.+"
    testCompile "org.easymock:easymock:3.+"
    testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.+"
    testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.+"
    
}

task fortifySetup(dependsOn: clean) << {
    ant.properties['build.compiler']='com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler'
    ant.typedef(name: 'sca', classname: 'com.fortify.dev.ant.SourceanalyzerTask',
    classpath: configurations.fortify.asPath)
}

task fortifyReport(dependsOn: compileJava) << {
    ant.sca(//buildid: buildID ,
        jdk: "1.8",
        debug:true,
        verbose:true,
        failonerror:true,
        scan: true,
        logFile:file("$buildDir/reports/fortify/Fortify.log"),
        resultsFile:file("$buildDir/reports/fortify/${fortify_build_id}.fpr")
        )
        {
            fileset(dir: 'src/main') {
                include(name: '**/*.java')
            }
        }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        
        property "sonar.host.url", "${System.env.SONAR_URL}"
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "${sonar_jdbc_url}"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "${sonar_jdbc_driver}"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "${sonar_jdbc_username}"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", "${sonar_jdbc_password}"
        property "sonar.projectKey", sonar_projectkey
        property "sonar.projectName", sonar_projectname
    }
}

task easyb  << {
       ant.taskdef(name: "easyb", classname:"org.easyb.ant.BehaviorRunnerTask", classpath: sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
    
       ant.easyb( classpath: sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath, failureProperty:'easyb_failed' ) {
           report( location:"${project.testResultsDir}/story.html", format:"html" )
           behaviors( dir: "src/test/behaviors" ) {
               include( name:"**/*.story" )
           }
      }
       ant.fail( if:'easyb_failed', message: 'Failures in easyb stories' )
       println "EasyB Story report can be found at ${project.testResultsDir}/story.html"
}

task runVolumeTest (dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'CoreAdvancedPrintFlowOrchestratorImplVolumeTest'
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

//make sure tests use test resources and test behaviors where TAF utils exist.
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            srcDir "src/test/resources"
            srcDir "src/test/behaviors"
        }
    }
}

// Pre-Release Artifactory Publishing
publishing{
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/prerelease' }
    }
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourcesJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.java
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/gradle-distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip
```

any suggestion how to resolve this.

Comment: Which repository does the dependency come from? I suppose you’ve already tried `implementation('com.zoom.ans:complete-order:dmz.100')`?

Comment: @Chriki - There is no change in the repository. I upgraded to gradle version to 6.0. If I rollback to older gradle version 5 or 4  then its working fine

Comment: Thanks, I understood that from your question. My hunch is that your configuration just _happened to work_ with Gradle 4/5 but was never officially supported and hence broke with Gradle 6. To verify that and to provide an answer, we need more information like what I’ve asked in my previous comment – or ideally a [mcve].

Comment: @Chriki updated with more details.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency notation `'com/zoom/ans:complete-order:dmz.100'` looks rather unusual. As already mentioned in the comments, my hunch is that it just happened to work with the older Gradle version, was never officially supported and hence broke with Gradle 6 now.

There are still many pieces missing to be absolutely certain but given that your dependency library seems to be published with `group 'com.zoom.ans'`, I would expect it to be resolvable using the following dependency declaration:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('com.zoom.ans:complete-order:dmz.100')
}
```

If it doesn’t work, then you should search the `prerelease` repository of your Artifactory server at http://repository.zoom.com:8081/artifactory/ for *artifacts* containing `complete-order`, `complete-order-dmz.100` or the like in their names. Usually you can then browse the repository tree to find the desired JAR file, select it and find a section “Dependency Declaration” on the right where you can select “Gradle” to see the correct group name, etc. (should look similar to [this](https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-api/6.4.1/artifactory-api-6.4.1.jar)).

Comment: com.zoom.ans:complete-order:dmz.100 library is there in the repo otherwise build will fail for the gradle version lower than gradle 6. I am wondering is there any change needed in the project com.zoom.ans:complete-order:dmz.100 to resolve this.  May be need to make some configuration changes in the project and then publish new version of com.zoom.ans:complete-order:dmz.100.

Comment: If that dependency is in the repo, then I would expect that my dependency declaration suggestion works. I’m still not clear if you’ve tried the update, though; have you? Otherwise republishing the dependency library might indeed be another option.